# Mule with Jersey dynamic hyperlinks

Tags: rest, dynamic, hyperlink, jersey, mule

Using mule 3.7 with a RESTful application and a design which calls for using dynamic links.  The Jersey documentation and examples call telling the application about the package to use links, and registering the DeclarativeLinkingFeature class on that package, then use @InjectLink annotation on the field of the class to receive the link.

This is problematic with Mule, and the Application structure is internal to Mule.  Without this registration, they @InjectLink has no effect, jersey does not populate the link.

Does anyone have a solution or work around, or even know if Mule has any provisions for implementing Dynamic Linking.  We have been able to find no information in the Mule documentation nor examples of Mule applications utilizing this feature.  Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the feature you want to use is not annotated with @Provider like this one: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/incubator/declarative-linking/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/linking/DeclarativeLinkingFeature.java

Create a class that implements Feature and that is annotated as @Provider and then register the features needed:

```
package com.package.features;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.linking.DeclarativeLinkingFeature;

@Provider
public class MyFeatures implements Feature {

@Override
public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
    return new DeclarativeLinkingFeature().configure(context);
  }
}
```

Then try to register the feature as so by scanning the package:

```
<jersey:resources>
   <component class="com.package.SomeResource"/>
   <jersey:package packageName="com.package.features" />
</jersey:resources>
```

Comment: We tried similar to that, and I tried again to verify the results.  That does indeed cause the @InjectLink to have a response, but not the one desired:  We receive an http error 500 for a get instead of the expected 200 with the message body of **javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;**.  This seems to indicate that a Hibernate validation failed, but even at trace levels no information is given as to the cause of the error, it is hidden down in the bowels of Mule/Jersey.